# PyTorch and PyTorch-operator kubeflow pipelines

Tags: pytorch, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I am trying to integrate pytorch and pytorch-operators into kubeflow pipelines and I am not able to get a good resource for both. Is this possible in the current implementation?

I understand that TFJob and PyTorchJob all run training containers on top of a kubernetes cluster but I am trying to integrate them into a pipeline.